# How to call a specific promise only once in Angular 1.5 when onInit hook is called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

There is a API call that I am making on the onInit function.

```
   vm.$onInit = function() {
        var callInProgress = false;
        var resultsLoaded = false;

        var url = '/api/times/cst';
        if(callInProgress === false && resultsLoaded ===false){
            callInProgress = true;
            HttpWrapper.send(url,{"operation":'GET'}).then(function(result){
                vm.times = result;
                resultsLoaded = true;
                },function(error){
                vm.errorInApi = true;
            });
        }
```

Now `$onInit` is being called multiple times hence the two flags `callInProgress, resultsLoaded` are being initialized every time.

So, the check is kind of not working.

The API is being called each time the `$onInit` is called, multiple times on initialization.

How can I make the call only once?
It has be called on `$onInit` though.

Comment: Why would $onInit() be called multiple times? If it's from multiple directives in a page then I could see that ...

Comment: @rrd Yes something like that.

Comment: Create a full data service, store the data in the service and only make the $http call when the data isn't already present.

Comment: So assuming multiple directives, why not put the code you want firing once, into the page controller instead?

Comment: This is exactly one of reasons why http requests and other business logic don't belong to controllers. Service is proper place for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advice wrapping the API call in a service like:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('services.common')
        .service('TimesService', TimesService);

    TimesService.$inject = ['HttpWrapper'];

    function TimesService(HttpWrapper) {
        var timesService = this;
        var timesResult = null;

        timesService.getTimes = getTimes;

        function getTimes() {
            if (!timesResult) {
                timesResult = HttpWrapper.send('/api/times/cst', {"operation": 'GET'});
            }
            return timesResult;
        }

        return timesService;
    }

})(angular);
```

and then inject it into your controller and use like `TimesService.getTimes().then(...)`, so the call to the API will be done only once on the first call of `TimesService.getTimes` (since the result would be stored in `timesResult` inside of the service).

Answer (score 0):

callInProgress and resultsLoaded are within the onInit function and part of the directive controller. They are going to get created each time you use the directive. Using a controller property on the containing controller to do something similar would be the way to go. You can use bindings to specify the controller property you need to keep this somewhat generic.

Comment: even the controller properties like vm.callInProgress etc are being initialized. So, no luck till now

Comment: I mean on the controller that contains the instances of the directive. You need them to be housed somewhere where there will only be one instance of them.